# JUnit5 Class Parametrization

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I want to parametrize tests at class level. Following example:

```
@BeforeAll
public void setup() {
        PropertiesLoader.loadProperties("remote.properties");
  //    PropertiesLoader.loadProperties("remote2.properties");
    }
```

I want to run tests with too remote.properties and remote2.properties.
Is there any annotation in JUnit 5 ?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions to parameterize your test. For adding values from a CSV you can use:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvFileSource(resources = "/params.csv", numLinesToSkip = 1)
```

The `numLinesToSkip` is only needed in case you want to skip a header inside the file.

If you want to use multiple files you need to use JUnit 5.2+ and check out `ArgumentsAggregator` and `ArgumentsAccessor`. You can combine multiple inputs into 1 single input and then call the test.
It is not possible to use them directly without some extra effort.